# The time cycle for business [python-telegram-bot] python

Tags: python

Я пишу своего бота телеграмм. И мне нужно реализовать задачу. Чтобы каждый час после покупки бизнеса у меня прибавлялись деньги.

Реализовывать datetime не получится, ибо можно перемотать время.

Пытался через threading.

```
if bussines:
 Timer = threading.Timer(5, ok())
 Timer.start()
def ok():
  print('Функция вызвалась через 5 секунд')
   Timer2 = threading.Timer(5, ok())
   Timer2.start()
```

После первой итерации всё падает с ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

1) ok нужно передавать без выполнения

```
threading.Timer(5, ok)
```

2) выравнивание кривое. print и Timer2 должны быть в один столбец.

Comment: Теперь всё работает, но после первой итерации, нету результата.
print('Функция вызвалась через 5 секунд')
Работает всего один раз.